# Generate Excel having Formula using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In the example below how to add the formula in individual **user totals** as the number of rows for the user can vary.

```
+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-------+
| Name |    Date      | Billable| Non-Billable | Total |
+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-------+
| abc  | 06/23/2012   |     860 |           10 |   870 |
|      | User Totals: |     860 |           10 |   870 |
| xyz  | 07/12/2012   |      45 |            0 |    45 |
|      | User Totals: |      45 |            0 |    45 |
| ccc  | 09/19/2013   |     165 |           35 |   200 |
|      | 10/15/2013   |     240 |            0 |   240 |
|      | User Totals: |     405 |           35 |   440 |
|      | Grand Totals |     1310|           45 |  1355 |
+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: Show us... what you have tried till now...

Comment: How would you do that in Excel? What formula would you use in Excel? Now, with that worked out, what happens if you try to set the very same formula using Apache POI?